# Lower bound for binomial random variable

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure

I'm looking for a lower bound for binomial random variable $X$~ $B(n,p)$, where
$p=(1+\epsilon)/2$  for $\epsilon >0$. 
I want to bound $Pr(X> n/2)$.

I know Suld's inequality, but it is good for the case $p=(1-\epsilon)/2$.

The best I could get is :

$Pr(X> n/2) =$  $\sum_{k=n/2}^{n}$ $ {n}\choose{k}$$p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ >
 $\sum_{k=n/2}^{n}$ $ {n}\choose{k}$$(1/2)^{n}$$=1/2$.

Which is not so good for me.

Is there any tighter bound?

Thanks!